Confirming if my ASRock Rack server is faulty
I purchased a second hand ASRock Rack 2U24E-ROM2 server online, and I'm fairly sure it is faulty, but wanted to double check with the community.
Alarm bells I'm seeing include -

The 2 digit display on the motherboard (Dr. Debug I believe) is blank.
VGA Output is extremely, extremely dodgy - I have once managed to get it to display anything after plugging and unplugging the monitor a few times.  (I've tried front and rear ports.   The question here is are the monitors faulty - the one is my TV and never worked very well with servers, the other is untested as its second hand and I don't have anything else that outputs VGAS.
I connected to the server using IPMI.  I was once able to see it showing a virtual screen showing it could not find the disks (this is OK, there are no disks installed).  Subsequently nothing.
When trying to power down and power up the server using IPMI I can hear the fans spinning up but the IPMI is saying the server has not started.
I downloaded the Postcodelog from IPMI and it says "No Post Code" (for 2 dates) and nothing else.

Thing I've tried -

Reseating memory
Reducing memory to 1 stick.
Removing button battery overnight and then reinserting
multiple monitors, multiple cables
different configurations powering each power supply

A couple of specific questions -

When plugging in the monitor and starting the server, should it show something on the screen right away/within seconds?  (When I went back to the seller he advised it could take up to 3 minutes for the screen to show?)
Should Dr. Debug always have output when the server is powered on?
If the fans are going full blast, but IPMI says the Host is currently Off, does that imply a motherboard/hardware failure?
Is there any other debug information that can confirm the server is a very sick puppy that I should be able to find in the IPMI console?


Yes; The motherboard sounds like it’s seen better days.
